# Segmentation Fault when entering chroot for LFS

Tags: debian, compiling, cross-compilation, lfs

I have been compiling an [LFS [Linux From Scratch]](https://linuxfromscratch.org) operating system, and thus far there were no errors. However, when I was compiling the Linux Kernel, I accidentally tripped on the power cord to my PC and when I try to enter the CHROOT for LFS, I simply get:
`root@debian:/# chroot $LFS`
`Segmentation fault`        
At first, I thought that bash was the problem, but even after I recompiled bash there was no difference. I am compiling LFS Version 11.1-systemd on an Intel Pentium 64-bit dual core processor. My host system is Debian GNU/Linux 11 [Bullseye]. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Please feel free to request any more information.

**EDIT: Result from *`strace -f -o /tmp/chroot.strace -e trace=execve chroot $LFS`***
------------------------------------------------------------
This command also errors out with `Segmentation fault`. I found a file named `/tmp/chroot.strace` and it contained:

```
512   execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-i"], 0x7fff5f2b4cf0 /* 24 vars */) = 0
512   --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x7ffd7f0bdeb8} ---
512   +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

**UPDATE: Results after recompiling GLIBC**
------------------------------------------------------------
I noticed that in the contents of `/tmp/chroot.strace`, bash was referring to `libc.so` and `libc.so.6`. This made me think that recompiling GLIBC would solve the problem. After I did so, when I tried `chroot $LFS`, the results were different:
`root@debian:/# chroot $LFS`                   
`chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory`
`root@debian:/#`  
The output of `strace chroot $LFS` is different, too. Here is a link to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/iggaubpJ
------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: sorry, i think those steps were not too useful, i can only tell the segv address looks like a stack address. you better learn how to debug using `gdb`. i suggest deleting these comments since they don't really clear up your problem.